# Meteor Facebook Login "You are using a display type of 'popup' in a large browser window or tab" Error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, meteor, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using meteor accounts-ui/accounts-facebook to login and am getting the following error.

**You are using a display type of 'popup' in a large browser window or tab. For a better user experience, show this dialog with our JavaScript SDK without specifying an explicit display type. The SDK will choose the best display type for each environment. Alternatively, set height and width on your window.open() call to properly size this dialog if you have special requirements precluding you from using the SDK. This message is only visible to developers of your**

http://goo.gl/IBmdjI (screenshot)

I haven't been able to find any information on the fix anywhere.  Is this something in meteor core that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a issue really its just a warning. Meteor doesn't use the JS Facebook SDK and gives a specified height/width for the facebook OAuth dialog & your browser size may be too big for the small popup (not too sure- looks ok in your screenshot).

If you disable your app from Sandbox mode/another user uses your app they wouldn't see this warning anymore.

The alternative is to use a redirect to facebook or a mobile display. The best option is the popup (what you have now) because it's the fastest: A redirect means your Meteor app has to reconnect up.

Comment: Ok cool, didnt know they wouldn't see it when I disable sandbox mode.  Not going to worry about it then.  Thanks!

Comment: @timmyg13 @Akshat It's actually shown only to the devs. Check the last sentence: `This message is only visible to developers of your application.`